# Only in XBMC mouse becomes too sensitive, can this be altered? Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mouse, touchpad, xbmc

This appears to be an age old question, asked and asked again, but no-one seems to have an answer, apart from use the keyboard, however, I want to use my mouse, is this possible?

I am finding that the mouse and touchpad works great in Ubuntu, however, when I switch to XBMC the mouse becomes hyper sensitive and flies everywhere with the smallest movement.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, but I think this is an issue across all Ubuntu releases.

Before this question is taken down for being too specific, could we at least try to find a solution. The people at XBMC do not care about this issue as far as I can tell.

So any help from those in 'the know' and 'with the skills' would be gratefully received.

Thank you

EDIT:
All resolved in KODI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Setting > System> Video Output"  from "Full screen" to "Windowed" .
Not perfect, but the mouse should be more easier to control now.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to duplicate this issue on a Samsung laptop running 14.04 and using XBMC, not Kodi.  I noticed the native resolution was to 1366x768 (system and xbmc.  I changed XBMC's resolution to a standard 1360x768 and the mouse acted normal.  Just putting this out in case anyone else has this issue and hasn't upgraded to kodi.  Settings change can be done in > System> Video Output > "Resolution" drop down